# c++ output of an array using void display(ostream&)

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [singly linked chain printing c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390449/singly-linked-chain-printing-c)

How can I get my void display function to display the array found in my Set function; also how would I reference that display function in my driver file?

Thanks.

Relevant files are below

header file

```
#ifndef SET_
#define SET_

using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

class Set
{
  private:

    unsigned Cap;    // Current capacity of the set
    unsigned Num;    // Current count of items in the set
    int * Pool;      // Pointer to array holding the items

  public:

    // Return information about the set
    //
    bool is_empty() const { return Num == 0; }
    unsigned size() const { return Num; }
    unsigned capacity() const { return Cap; }

    // Initialize the set to empty
    //
    Set()
    {
      Cap = Num = 0;
      Pool = NULL;
    }

    // De-initialize the set
    //
    ~Set();

    // Initialize the set using an existing set
    //
    Set( const Set& );

    // Assign into the set from another set
    //
    Set& operator=( const Set& );

    // Test for presence of a specified item in the set
    //
    bool is_present( int ) const;

    // Remove a specified item from the set, if possible
    //
    bool remove( int );

    // Insert a specified item into the set, if possible
    //
    bool insert( int );

    // Display the set
    //
    void display( ostream& ) const;

    // Produce the union of two sets
    //
    friend Set operator+( const Set&, const Set& );

    // Produce the intersection of two sets
    //
    friend Set operator^( const Set&, const Set& );
};

#endif
```

my implementation file

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include "/user/cse232/Projects/project07.set.h"

void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
{
        bool swapped = true;
        int j = 0;
        int tmp;

        while(swapped)
        {
                j++;
                for(int i = 0; i < n-j; i++)
                {
                        if(arr[i] > arr[i+1])
                        {
                                tmp = arr[i];
                                arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                                arr[i+1] = tmp;
                                swapped = true;
                        }
                }
        }
}

Set::~Set()
{
        Cap = 0;
        Num = 0;
        delete [] Pool;
        Pool = NULL;
}

/*bool Set::is_present(int X) const
{
        bool Flag = false;

        while(unsigned Z=0;Z<=Num;Z++)
        {
                if(Pool[Z] = X)
                {
                        Flag = true;
                }
        }
        return Flag;
}*/
bool Set::insert(int X)
{
        bool Flag = false;

        if(Num == Cap)
        {
                //reallocate memory
                const unsigned Inc = 3;

                try
                {
                        int * temp = new int[Cap+Inc];

                        for(unsigned J=0; J<Num; J++)
                        {
                                temp[J] = Pool[J];
                        }
                        delete [] Pool;
                        Pool = temp;
                }
                catch(std::bad_alloc)
                {
                        cerr << "\n*** UNABLE TO INCREASE CAPACITY ***\n\n";
                }
        }
        if(Num < Cap)
        {
                //insert stuff
                Pool[Num+1] = X;
                Num++;

                bubbleSort(Pool,Num);

                Flag = true;
        }

        return Flag;
}
void display(ostream &out) const
{
        //print the array
}
```