# singly linked chain printing c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to pick my chain in the format {1,2,3,4,etc}. You can find the header file below which will have the layout of the nodes. I am just confused on how I should go about cycling through my list to print out Item.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

set.h

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

class Set
{
  private:

    struct Node
    {
      int Item;      // User data item
      Node * Succ;   // Link to the node's successor
    };

    unsigned Num;    // Current count of items in the set
    Node * Head;     // Link to the head of the chain

  public:

    // Return information about the set
    //
    bool is_empty() const { return Num == 0; }
    unsigned size() const { return Num; }

    // Initialize the set to empty
    //
    Set();

    // Insert a specified item into the set, if possible
    //
    bool insert( int );

    // Display the set
    //
    void display( ostream& ) const;

};
```

Comment: It's hard to get your question..Can you just keep the useful code,btw?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, if this is homework please mark it as such

Comment: Please **don't** ***tag*** it as homework, however. The homework tag is deprecated.

Comment: If you know how your linked list works, I suggest you look at the code you no-doubt have that finds the *end* of you linked list, copy it, and change it to print each node before advancing to the next.

Comment: If you don't know how a linked list works, I suggest you search the web for "linked list tutorial".  The better ones have pretty diagrams.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Suppose your list is cyclical, you can use this:

```
struct Node *n = begin;

if (n != NULL) {
    //do something on it
    ...
    for (n = begin->Succ; n != begin; n = n->Succ) {
    }
}
```

or

```
struct Node *n = begin;
if (n != NULL) {        
    do {        
        //do something
        ...
        n = n->Succ;
    } while (n != begin)
}
```

Comment: The first one will not work if the list is circular and `begin->Succ`==>`begin`. It will skip the node outright. Also, it will seg-fault if `begin` is NULL. The second proposal avoids the list-of-one problem, but like the first, seg-fault if `begin` is NULL. Either way, I hope the OP accounts for this when using this answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Missing the Null pointer check is my mistake. However, I do think about the first node question in the first one, you should see the `//do something on it` comment  after the first line of code.

Comment: The second is now *much* better. The first still has whatever action is going to be taken required to be in *two* places; one outside the for-loop for the first node, one *inside* the for-loop for subsequent nodes. This answer as a solution for circular lists would be best-served to drop the first method out *entirely*. Perhaps replace it with a non-circular solution to cover both circular and non-circular cases.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two recommendations:  1) Sort the list first, then print all nodes; 2) Create another list (indices) to the data and sort those links (don't need data in those nodes).

### Sorting List First

An often used technique is to order the nodes in the order you want them printed.  This should involve changing the link fields.
Next, start at the head node and print each node in the list (or the data of each node in the list).

### Using an Index list

Create another linked list without the data fields.  The links in this list point to the data fields in the original list.  Order the new list in the order you want the nodes printed.
This technique preserves the order of creation of the first list and allows different ordering schemes.

### Changing Links

Since you're writing your own Linked List, the changing of the links is left as an exercise as I'm not getting paid to write your code.  There are many examples on SO as well as the web for sorting and traversing linked lists.

Comment: I'll probably get downvoted or no votes because I didn't provide any diagrams, or code examples.  There are plenty of these around already.

Comment: Btw, I esp like the index-list, and use it often. Its amazing what you can accomplish with a big'ol'raft of pointers when you know how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to do something like this:

```
void Set::display(ostream &out) const {
    for(int i=0; i<Num; i++) {
        out << Pool[i] << " ";
    }
    out << endl;
}
```

An `ostream` behaves as `cout` would.

Comment: You don't display an `ostream`, you display *to* the `ostream`. `ostream` doesn't have an `str` member.

Comment: @interjay thank you, i edited. it's the "i'm on vacation in 2 minutes" effect, I was thinking about ostringstream.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to get your question. If you want to print the array to screen you should consider writing a `display()` like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
void Set::display() const {
   ostream_iterator<int> out_it (cout," ");
   copy(Pool,Pool+Num,out_it);   
   cout << endl;
}
```

or if you want to write to a  `ostream&` (as it is pointed out in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13163962/1714661) by @alestanis)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
void Set::display(ostream &out) const {
   ostream_iterator<int> out_it (out," ");
   copy(Pool,Pool+Num,out_it);   
   out << endl;
}
```

Comment: how would i then utilize display?

Comment: If you implement both versions (i.e. `display` is overloaded), you may call either `display()` or `display(cout)` (from an instance of `Set`).

Comment: Yeah, this is a school project and one of the requirements is that I cannot edit the header file. Basically I am/was unsure of how to implement

// Display the set
    //
    void display( ostream& ) const;

part of the header

Comment: @sharkman, then just go ahead with the second version. btw you can put the `#include <iterator>` also in the implementation file (.cpp)

Answer (score 1):

Without testing, I'd do something like this. (Assumes the last node has `Succ` set to `NULL`, as I would recommend it does.)

```
void LoopList(struct Node *head)
{
    for (struct Node *p = head; p != null; p = p->Succ)
    {
        // Do whatever with this node
        Print(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess what is confusing me is how to implement with the given function "void display( ostream& ) const;" maybe I am over thinking..

Answer (score 0):

I think I was over thinking it. Anyway here is what I ended up doing. Now I just need to add some formatting for the commas and im all set.

```
Node * Temp;
Temp = new (nothrow) Node;
Temp = Head;
out << "{";
while(Temp->Succ)
{
      out << Temp->Item;
      Temp = Temp->Succ;
}
out << '}' << endl;
```

Comment: Why do you have the `Temp = new (nothrow) Node;` bit? It serves no purpose, except leaking memory...  You should also check to make sure that Head isn't null.